# Error when sending json as environment variable to cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have set up a secret called GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS(which is a json) in my repository, then I have set up this yaml to deploy my code to a Cloud Function on Google:

```
- name: Deploy
  id: 'deploy'
  uses: 'google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v1'
  with:
    name: ''
    runtime: 'python311'
    entry_point: ''
    source_dir: ./
    project_id: 
    env_vars: |
      GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS=${{ secrets.GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS }}
```

But when I run the job, it gives me the following error: `google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to parse KEY=VALUE pair ""project_id": "project_id"": missing "="`. How can I send this variable correctly to the Cloud Function?

I have set up the json environment variable manually via cloud console, and it worked just fine, but I need it to be set on the deployment. Anyone have any ideas how to do it properly? The other variables that I have set are working just fine, but this variable with the JSON is being the problem.

Comment: Use single quotes around `${{...}}` i.e. `GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS='${{ secrets.GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS }}'`.

Comment: Hello @Azee! That did not work either, it splits my GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS that is supposed to be a JSON, into a lot of new environment variables using the key:value inside the JSON.

Comment: Hi! Please take a look at the implementation how `env_vars` are handled. Maybe, you need to escape those but I'm not sure. I'll take a look at that later and update here.

Comment: Thanks, @Azeem, I will try to figure something out in the meanwhile.

Comment: Just looked at the action's [`inputs`](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions?tab=readme-ov-file#inputs) and there's this `env_vars_file` input param. In its [example](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/blob/main/tests/env-var-files/test.good.yaml) YAML file, it has `JSONKEY: '{"bar":"baz"}'`. So, technically, single quoting should work as suggested above. Are you sure there's no newline in your JSON and it's all one single single line?

Comment: You can use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to compact it if `GDRIVE_API_CREDENTIALS` isn't already compact. You may use https://jqplay.org/ to do this online ([example](https://jqplay.org/s/Oe-11567kmc)). You may also use escape the nested quotes as well with `jq` e.g. `jq -c '. | @json' <<< '{"k":"v"}'` and its output will be `"{\"k\":\"v\"}"`.

Comment: @Azeem, thank you for your help so far! I tried the `jq` but still did not work :( I tried using single quotes around the variable, without the single quotes, still getting the error: `google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions failed with: failed to parse KEY=VALUE pair "\"project_id\":\"project_id\"": missing "="`. Maybe it isn't really possible?

Comment: The error is coming from [here](https://github.com/google-github-actions/actions-utils/blob/78b90a7065c3c65dcbbd9f434484ba6c835efa6c/src/kv.ts#L50). It splits at the comma (because it isn't specific to JSON format) hence the failure. Whereas giving arguments via [file](https://github.com/google-github-actions/actions-utils/blob/78b90a7065c3c65dcbbd9f434484ba6c835efa6c/src/kv.ts#L92-L119) i.e. using `env_vars_file` honors JSON and YAML formats; so it should work for your use case.

Comment: After going through the complete implementation of `kv.ts` [here](https://github.com/google-github-actions/actions-utils/blob/78b90a7065c3c65dcbbd9f434484ba6c835efa6c/src/kv.ts), the only valid solution for you would be to use a YAML file just like this [example](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/blob/main/tests/env-var-files/test.good.yaml). Apparently, providing a simple `key=value` would break and to provide a JSON file the nested value will have to be escaped properly. So, use a YAML file and observe the precedence of `env_vars` over `env_vars_file`

Comment: @Azeem I will try that out, thank you so much for your help and effort! Have a great week :)

Comment: From above conversation, I believe your problem is resolved. If so, Can you share the solution as answer so that it helps others too.